# Switching from Jmockit to mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, jmockit

so I decided to move from jmockit to mockito and it seems strange to me I can't understand how some things work in mockito

I have that simple @BeforeEach method and when my objects are mocked I always get a null pointer exception

```
@Mock
public EntityManager entityManager;

@Mock
public TimerSessionBean timerSessionBean;

@Mock
public Client client;

private CaseSetReminder caseSetReminder;

private Request request;
private Message message;

@BeforeEach
final void beforeEach() {
    request = new Request();
    message = new Message();

    String spaceId = "SPACE_ID";
    String threadId = "THREAD_ID";

    caseSetReminder = new CaseSetReminder();
    caseSetReminder.entityManager = entityManager;
    caseSetReminder.timerSessionBean = timerSessionBean;

    ThreadM thread = new ThreadM();

    thread.setName("spaces/" + spaceId + "/thread/" + threadId + "");
    Sender sender = new Sender();
    sender.setName("MyName");
    message.setSender(sender);
    message.setThread(thread);

    Reminder reminder = new Reminder("Do Something", ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Athens")).plusMinutes(10),
            "DisplayName", "Europe/Athens", spaceId, threadId);

    reminder.setReminderId(1);
    timerSessionBean.nextReminderDate = reminder.getWhen();
}
```

it always throws me

> Argument passed to verify() is of type TimerSessionBean and is not a
>   mock!
>
> Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
>
> See the examples of correct verifications:
>
> ```
> verify(mock).someMethod();
>
> verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
>
> verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();
> ```

but that's not true its timerSessionBean is mocked and my syntax is correct

and that's the method I run that triggers the beforeEach method

```
@Test
void mockitoTest() throws Exception {

    final String expectedDate = "12/12/2019 12:00 athens";
    message.setText("remind me ' set next reminder Test' at " + expectedDate);
    request.setMessage(message);

    // Already set in mock a nextReminder that is to be in 10 mins from now()
    //So this should not be set
    caseSetReminder.setRequest(request);
    caseSetReminder.setReminder();

    //Verifies that setNextReminder is called 0 times because Input reminderDate is AFTER the current
    verify(timerSessionBean , times(1)).setNextReminder(Mockito.any(Reminder.class), Mockito.any(ZonedDateTime.class));

}
```

I hope you guys can help me figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you init the Mockito engine:

```
@BeforeEach
final void beforeEach() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  ..
```

or

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) 
 public class TestClass{
```

also, you cannot set fields of a mocked class like:

```
timerSessionBean.nextReminderDate = reminder.getWhen();
```

try using `doReturn()`, `when()`, `then()` to configure behavior

Comment: can you explain how to configure timerSessionBean with when, then, doReturn and you solved my problem with  **MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);**

Comment: you expect certain out based on method invocation with certain input.. doReturn("return string").when(mock).mockMethod(param1). Go through the basics of Mockito its to broad of a subject for this post

Comment: I am hard stuck trying to find any light in my tunnel and I still can't find any my problem is `timerSessionBean.nextReminderDate = reminder.getWhen();` and yet i can't find how to set fields in mockito